# how to retrieve data from Json file and displaying it in HTML dropdown...?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, json.net

Hi i have developed simple Html Page using AngularJS which displays Manufacturer Name in drop down on user selection correspondent Manufacturer Id  will get displayed in the below text box.
I have used ng-repeat directive to display manufacturer names in HTML Dropdown and ng-model directive to display selected manufacturer Id.

```
here is my HTML CODE 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="jsonapp">
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body> 
<div ng-controller='JsonController'>
    <span>Please select a Manufacturer:</span>

     <li ng-model="Manufacturers" ng-repeat="Manufnames in Manufacturers" style="width:350px;">
            {{Manufnames.ManufacturerName}}
     </li>  
// here i wanted to Display Drop Down which will display Manufacturer Names
    <input type="text" /> //here i wanted to display correspondent Manufacturer ID 
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('jsonapp', []);
    app.controller('JsonController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('Pipes.json') 
        .success(function (response) { $scope.Manufacturers = response.Pipesmanuf; });
    });
    </script>
 // since i have stored both Json and HTML on Same Folder i am directly passing json filename to http.get() funtion to retrive data
</body>
</html> 

// I have stored both HTML File and  Json File in same folder My Json file contains following data:

{
"Pipesmanuf": [
    {
        "ManufacturerId": 1,
        "ManufacturerName": "Avonplast",
        "Products": "PIPES",
        "ManufacturerLogo": "C:\Users\Suprith\Desktop\Manufacturerlogos\Pipes\avonplast.jpg"
    },
    {
        "ManufacturerId": 2,
        "ManufacturerName": "BEC",
        "Products": "PIPES",
        "ManufacturerLogo": "C:\Users\Suprith\Desktop\Manufacturerlogos\Pipes\BEC.png"
    }
]
}
```

I am New to Angular JS please suggets me how to Load data from JSON File and displaying it using HTML DropDowns or HTML List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your JSON is invalid due to the directory paths. Backslashes `\` are escape characters. This causes the parse to fail. So simply change your JSON to

```
{  
   "Pipesmanuf":[  
      {  
         "ManufacturerId":1,
         "ManufacturerName":"Avonplast",
         "Products":"PIPES",
         "ManufacturerLogo":"C:\\Users\\Suprith\\Desktop\\Manufacturerlogos\\Pipes\\avonplast.jpg"
      },
      {  
         "ManufacturerId":2,
         "ManufacturerName":"BEC",
         "Products":"PIPES",
         "ManufacturerLogo":"C:\\Users\\Suprith\\Desktop\\Manufacturerlogos\\Pipes\\BEC.png"
      }
   ]
}
```

This way you are escaping the escape character.

Beyond that, getting the list into a drop down is almost exactly like your list loop:

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="Manufnames in Manufacturers">{{Manufnames.ManufacturerName}}</option>
</select>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LXvFNZBVzCIZot96JhgP?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the official tutorial : https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_01 .

They do something similar specially the step 11.

Basically, if you want something nice and reusable, you should use a service to request the data in your file. Then inject this service in your controller and get the data then display it in the view. With the tutorial, I think you can handle it. Good look!